# a program that returns true if a string contains only digits

Tags: haskell

I want to make a program that returns true if a string contains only digits in Haskell.

This is my attempt:

```
checkNum :: String -> Bool
checkNum xs = ((length (filter isDigit xs )) == length (xs))
```

This is the error I get:

> Not in scope: `isDigit'

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to import `Data.Char`. Note you can also use `all`.

Comment: [Hoogle is your friend.](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=isDigit).  The only result tells you that it's in package `base` in module `Data.Char`.  You have to import a module to use it using `import Module.Name`, e.g. `import Data.Char`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)

checkNum :: String -> Bool
checkNum = all isDigit
```

Comment: @Shiran There is nothing wrong with your code except the import. This code by Chris is just shorter and more nice.

Comment: @Shiran And it works for infinite `String`s with at least one non-digit, but I don't know if that's important to you at this point :-)

Comment: @Shiran Besides what Sibi and yatima2975 pointed out, another issue with `length` is that it has to run down through the whole list, so it gets slower as the list grows. As a rule of thumb you should only use `length` if you actually need to know the length of the list; if you are only using it to find out something else there almost always is a better way of doing it.